# how to stop timers in tabbar's three viewcontrollers from single viewcontroller in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Hi i am developing an iphone applicaiton, in my application i have a scenario like a UItabbar controller having two UIviewcontrollers. in each view controller i have seperate nstimer.

I want to know that how to stop all timers from one of the view controller.

My timer code as follows

```
 -(void)startTimer
 {
     if (_timer == nil)
     {
         _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(setProgress)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
     }
}
- (void)stopTimer
{
     if (_timer != nil)
     {
         [_timer invalidate];
         _timer = nil;
     }
}
 -(void)setProgress
 {
     [self stopTimer];
     [self initmethod];
 }
```

if i navigate to any other page from one of the uiviewcontroller i just stoped and invoks by callback method. if i navigate to other page from a one of the uiviewcontroller means i want to stop all timers in all three uiviewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass uitabbarcontroller and add a method 'stopAllTimers'. That method will iterate through its array of viewControllers, sending each a 'stopTimer' message.

Answer (score 1):

of cause, you could use NSNotification's in all the VC's

but if your repeating timers are mostly needed for updates of the VC's, the better way would be to save "last seen" time for each of them (in viewDidDisappear) and check if that time saved is distant enough in viewWillAppear method

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct way to do this.

But, you may consider using a shared bool variable ,say *shouldStopTimer*, which can be accessed in all viewControllers.

Add a check in your "*setProgress*" method if *shouldStopTimer* is NO.
Invalidate the timer if you find *shouldStopTimer* as YES in you "*setProgress*" method.

Else

You can use NSNotification to invalidate the timers in their respective viewControllers.